# Strange black pixel on edge when generating with gdaldem -hillshade

Tags: raster, gdal, hillshade

I'm getting a strange result when I'm generating an hillshade with the gdaldem hillshade command.

Here is my command (see the compute_edges parameter):

```
    /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/gdaldem hillshade -compute_edges -alt 90 -z 8 -s 111120 /Users/jflegendre/Documents/GDAL_PROJECTS/MP/01-DEM_MERGED/out.tiff /Users/jflegendre/Documents/GDAL_PROJECTS/MP/02-HILLSHADED_DEM/hillshaded_dem.tiff
```

Here is a section of the output raster:

[image]

I've also tried to clip the result with a perimeter shapefile, but there still had some black pixels.

I've tried too the nearblack gdal command without effect. The image that you can see in this post is the result of the nearblack command.
So I'm stuck actually.

Can someone help me on this?

Regards

Comment: What is the no data value of your output image?

Comment: The no data value is 0.

Comment: It's probably a display issue.  Try to change your no data value (in qgis, or using gdal_edit.py) to an out of range value.